# Cell contains some words but not others

Tags: function, google-sheets, count, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to see if a student received all A's (A+, A, A-), which would make the statement true and if they received even one grade other that an a then it would be false. This is the function I've tried, but it always comes back with false.

```
=AND(COUNT(SEARCH(C35:C37,D9:D16))>0,COUNT(SEARCH(D35:D45,D9:D16))=0)
```

[image: photo]

Comment: Ops! yes! I just edited it! C35:37 are the grades A+, A, and A-.

Comment: You're right! I did mean B. I actually meant to put b33:35. I don't know why it said C. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUM(IF(REGEXMATCH(FILTER($C$3:$F$10, $C$2:$F$2=$A17), "A"), 1, ))=
 COUNTA(FILTER($C$3:$F$10, $C$2:$F$2=$A17)))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am having one problem though.. If the whole row, say M3, is blank because grades haven't been recorded yet, it still shows it as being true. Is there a way to fix this?